# symfony4 FOS Rest bundle verisoning is not working

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony4, jms-serializer, api-versioning

I have tried the **symfony4** with fos bundle rest api versioning and it url routing is working , but api versioning is not working. Please find my below code and i have missed out anything.

**My Url :**

```
example.com/v2/api/guesttest
example.com/v1/api/guesttest
```

when we accessing the above urls always returning the same set of reults v1.

**Routes.yml**

```
guest_api:
    path:  /{version}/api/guesttest
    controller: App\Controller\TestController::test1
    condition:  "request.attributes.get('version') == 'v1'"
    requirements: 
        version: 'v1|v2'
```

**fos_rest.yaml**

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener:  true
    allowed_methods_listener:  true
    routing_loader: 
        include_format: false
    body_listener: true

    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: ^/api, prefer_extension: false, fallback_format: json, priorities: [ json ] }
            - { path: ^/, prefer_extension: true, fallback_format: html, priorities: [ html ] }

    versioning:
        enabled: true
        default_version: v1
```

**TestController.php**

```
/**
 * @Version("v1")
 * @NamePrefix("v1")
 * 
*/

class TestController extends FOSRestController
{
    public function test1() 
    {
         return new Response("success....!");
        exit;
    }
}
```

**jms_serializer.yaml**

```
jms_serializer:
    visitors:
        xml:
            format_output: '%kernel.debug%'

    metadata:
        cache: file
        debug: "%kernel.debug%"
        file_cache:
            dir: "%kernel.cache_dir%/serializer"
        auto_detection: true
```

Reference links:

1. [github](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/1958)
2. [Symfony-verioning](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/versioning.html)